# What does the graph of this field looks like?

Tags: vectors, graphing-functions, vector-fields

A Field is given by $\frac{x}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}\hat i+\frac{y}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}\hat j$ 
where $\hat i$ $\hat j$ are unit vectors along $x$ and $y$ axis respectively.  How would graph of this field would look like on the cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a few arrows on a piece of paper? That really is the best way to get a feel for what a field looks like, and why.

Comment: Use wolframalpha...

Comment: It might be helpful to consider that this field is simply $\mathbf{e_R}/R$ in cylindrical polar coordinates.

Comment: @Arthur concentric circles ?

Comment: At $(1,1)$, what direction does the field point? At $(1,0)$? At $(0,1)$? Does that look like concentric circles?